# Is there a service that allows to hedge for bitcoin and has an API?

Tags: api, trading

I want to hegde Bitcoin with USD because of the high volatility of Bitcoin.

Is there a service that offers hedges for Bitcoin and has an API that I can use with PHP?

Comment: Downvoting without a comment does not help!

Comment: @erik: The shape that question was in, before it was edited, definitely didn't need an explanation for a downvote (= "This question does not show any previous research; **it is unclear** or not useful.").

Answer (score 0):

You should go to [New York Hedge Fund](http://nysohedge.com/), they provide bitcoin hedge. I am not sure if they have an API, but I suppose they have. See the news on [Coindesk](http://www.coindesk.com/bitcoin-as-safe-as-wire-transfers-says-ny-hedge-fund/).